# Can stagnate be used as a noun?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I couldn't remember stalemate for some reason so opted to use the phrase, "put us in a stagnate". In this context, would that be appropriate?

Full sentence: I'm worried that a lack of coordination would put us in a stagnate.

None of the dictionaries I've seen seem to approve of it, but I can't help but feel this is a fine usage of the word.

Comment: I think if you check a dictionary, you'll find *stagnate* purely as a verb. // One noun would be *stagnation*.  I'm worried that a general lack of coordination would put us in a period of stagnation.

Comment: In what context did you use this phrase?

Comment: @Brook Kelsey Full sentence: I'm worried that a lack of coordination would put us in a stagnate.

Comment: I understand you are using it in a sentence. In what greater context (I.e. poem, essay, novel etc.)?

Comment: "I'm worried that a lack of coordination would stagnate us." Or: "I'm worried that a lack of coordination would put us in a bind."

Comment: @Cosmic_Explorer it's better to expand the question, than to repeat in comment one of its sentences.

Comment: The sentence is understandable, but it hurts my ears. Your usage is highly nonstandard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we're talking about commonly recognized usage, then *stagnation* is the noun and *stagnate* is the verb. Here is *[stagnation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stagnation)*, a noun, in Merriam-Webster:

> : a stagnant state or condition : a state or condition marked by lack of flow, movement, or development

And here is *[stagnate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stagnate)*, a verb:

> : to become or remain stagnant

So for your example sentence, it would be better to write:

> I'm worried that a lack of coordination would put us in **stagnation**. (using the noun form)
>
> I'm worried that we would **stagnate** if we do not coordinate. (using the verb form)

---

It's hard to say why **stagnate** would sound fine as a nonce noun to you. For example, the *-ate* suffix marks *stagnate* as a verb from Latin, and several other verbs share that form (*segregate*, *aggregate*, *aggravate*, *ingratiate*) (OED, "[-ate, suffix3](https://oed.com/view/Entry/12404)"). That said, there are also nouns that have an *-ate* ending (*senate*, *prelate*, *mandate*) (OED, "[-ate, suffix1](https://oed.com/view/Entry/12402)"). So it would be possible to hear the word with its ending and think, "This sounds noun-ish as well as verb-ish."

That said, this hypothetical usage is rare enough that the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) turns up zero results for "stagnate_n" (stagnate as a noun) and "a stagnate" (stagnate with an article, so either a noun or adjective), but it turns up 152 results for "stagnate_v" (stagnate as a verb). Their largest corpus, [NOW: News on the Web](https://www.english-corpora.org/now/), turns up zero results for "stagnate_n" but 3857 results for "stagnate_v." Strangely, "a stagnate" does turn up ten results, but they all use *stagnate* as an adjective in a peculiar fashion. It feels like a misspelling of *stagnant*. A few examples:

> it's a stagnate case
>
> they just look like a stagnate team, going through the motions.
>
> including a stagnate and aging population

So if *stagnate* is ever used as a noun, it's so rare that a misspelling of the adjective *stagnant* is more common.